# Link on image in PDF using tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

How to add hyper link on image in generated PDF using tcpdf

I am using below code to generate bar code. I want to add hyperlink on bar code.

```
$pdf->write2DBarcode("text goes here", 'QRCODE,H', 30, 380, 75, 75, '', 'N');
```

Comment: Add the link as below,
$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.google.com', 'QRCODE', H, 30, 380, 75 ,'', 'N');

Comment: According to http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_050.phps , the code in the comment of @user3040610 should work. Is the barcode being created on pdf? When you read the barcode via a program, is the value as expected?

Comment: this is the code for generate bar code but I want to hyperlink on bar code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Link()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ab87bf1826384fbfe30eb499d42f1d994) to create a link area below your barcode.

```
TCPDF::Link($x, $y, $w, $h, $link, $spaces = 0)
```

---

```
$pdf->Link(30, 380, 75, 75, 'http://www.google.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output the barcode in various formats. See the `examples/barcodes` directory in the framework library. One of those formats is HTML. Maybe try using that and the `writeHTML` method:

```
// You should have this file in the library:
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/tcpdf_barcodes_2d_include.php'); 

// set the barcode content and type
$barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode('BARCODE TEXT', 'DATAMATRIX');

// output the barcode as HTML object
$barcodeHTML = $barcodeobj->getBarcodeHTML(6, 6, 'black');

$html = '<a href="http://www.google.com">' . $barcodeHTML . '</a>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```